Counting words in a LaTeX document without code blocks
I have a document that I am writing that involves a lot of code blocks written as :
\begin{python}
# Some code
\end{python}

Using the listings package to form this into code blocks.
I want to get a word count that does not count LaTeX commands, but that also ignores anything inside these code blocks. As far as I can tell TexCount does not have this functionality, but please let me know if it does.
Also, if these can be ignored when counting words, can it be done so that only python blocks are ignored, and itemize ones are kept?

How do you count words? You could probably pipe your .tex files through a small program that removed these blocks you want to ignore, and then you count the words in these modified files.

See also https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/members/it/faqs/latex/word-count and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document
